# Retrieving value from this dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a tuple of dictionary that looks like this;

```
names_dict = {0: ('CV', '4'), 1: ('PR', '8'), 2: ('SC', '2'), 3: ('SR', '3'), 4: ('SP', '7'), 5: ('Temperature', '1')}
```

Next I have this variable which tells me what to retrieve;

```
name = 'Temperature'
```

I have this function `retrieve_value(names_dict , name)` such that when name is `'Temperature'`, the function returns 1. If name is `'SP'`, the function returns 7.

How can the function be done in python? I am using python 2.7.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this:

```
>>> next((value[1] for value in names_dict.values() if value[0]==name), None)
'1'
```

create a function:

```
>>> def my_function(my_dict, name):
...     return next((value[1] for value in my_dict.values() if value[0]==name), None)
... 
>>> my_function(names_dict, 'Temperature')
'1'
>>> my_function(names_dict, 'SP')
'7'
```

Comment: Excellent idea, but to avoid returning a list (rather than the value as requested) you could index with `[0]`, or use a `next` with a genexp as first arg and `None` as second arg if you're not sure the queried-for name can be found.

Comment: @AlexMartelli thanks for the Information , I updated it as u said :)

Comment: ...but still w/o the second arg `, None` as I rec'd (in which case you need extra parentheses around the genexp).  I've already upvoted you but I'm urging you to move from "good" to "great"!-)

Comment: Thanks. I like the answer. But what is the difference between `next` and the original one? The original one works fine.

Comment: yep in original one it return as list, but using next it return the element of list, next iterate over list

Answer (score 4):

You can write a list comprehension and retrieve the first element:

```
>>> next(value[1] for value in names_dict.itervalues() if value[0] == 'CV')
'4'
```

That will raise a `StopIteration` if the key you provide isn't found, but you can add a default if you prefer:

```
>>> next((value[1] for value in names_dict.itervalues() if value[0] == 'XXX'), None)
>>>
```

Comment: Heh, just what I was suggesting at the same time in a comment to Hackaholic's answer -- upvoting you too, as I had him, for fairness!-)

Comment: Correct answer but I have already used Hackaholic's before yours came in. So, I chose his as the answer. But thanks a lot. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the **values** of your dict using `dict.values`, which returns a list containing your dict values, just as @Hackaholic answered.

In case the dict is too large, that `dict.values` may be inefficient, use `dict.itervalues` instead, which returns an **iterator** over the values of your dict but not a **list**

In python3, things are changed. `dict.values` returns an iterator but not a list any more.

Comment: Nice, was just wondering if their was an iterator version of `values()`, apart from `iteritems()`.